# Invoice Cancellation error

Tags: magento2

I have added a mass action to Sales->Invoice Grid. It is working fine when I select a single item from the grid. But on multiple selects it throws the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice\Item::setOrderItem() must be an instance of Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item, null given, called in /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Invoice/Relation.php on line 54 and defined in /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Invoice/Item.php on line 129

Here is the mass action controller:

```
    <?php

namespace Vendor\MassActionCancel\Controller\Adminhtml\Invoice;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface;

class CancelInvoice extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\AbstractMassAction
{

    protected $orderManagement;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Filter $filter,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice $invoiceModel,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $filter);
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->orderManagement = $orderManagement;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->invoiceModel = $invoiceModel;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    }

    protected function massAction(AbstractCollection $collection)
    {
        $invoice_not_canceled = array();
        $invoice_canceled = array();
        $itemsArray = $this->request->getPostValue('selected');
        foreach ($itemsArray as $key => $invoiceId) {
            $invoice = $this->invoiceModel->load($invoiceId);
            if(!$invoice->isCanceled()){
                $invoice->cancel();
                $invoice->setState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice::STATE_CANCELED);
                $invoice->save();
                $invoice_canceled[] = $invoiceId;
            }
            else{
                $invoice_not_canceled[] = $invoiceId;
            }
        }
        if(!empty($invoice_not_canceled)){
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Following Invoices could not be canceled: '.implode(',', $invoice_not_canceled)));
        }
        if(!empty($invoice_canceled)){
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Following Invoices canceled: '.implode(',', $invoice_canceled)));
        }
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('sales/invoice/');
    }
}
```

It is called when save() method is called for the second item. Also the error is not thrown always but at random times.